# How to trigger a function repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a randomising function for a game in **javascript and jquery**. I have written this to randomise the position of a square in a **8x8x64px** grid, and give the player a point when their character moves over it. **The function works once, but wont repeat**.

The relevant script

Every time the player moves it searches for

```
if (xNum==ptX && yNum==ptY) {
                        getPoint();
                        pointRand();
                    }
```

`yNum` and `xNum` is the player's coordinates and `ptY` and `ptX` is the point's. Movement occurs on keyUp for the arrow keys, and the if is also executed then.

Corresponding functions

```
//Score
var ptAllow = true;
var pt = 0;
var ptX = 7;
var ptY = 7;
var yPt = ptX*64+"px";
var xPt = ptY*64+"px";
function getPoint() {
    if (ptAllow == true) {
        pt++;
        document.getElementById("scoreCounter").innerHTML = "score: "+pt;
        document.getElementById("scoreFin").innerHTML = "score: "+pt;
    }
}

function pointRand() {
    ptX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    ptY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    ptX--;
    ptY--;
    yPt = ptX*64+"px";
    xPt = ptY*64+"px";
    $("#point").animate({"left": xPt, "top": yPt}, 100);
}
```

Like I said, It works perfectly the first time you move over a point, but after that nothing happens. . ptAllow is set to false once the player hits an obstacle, and the game is over.
Edit: There are no errors in the browser console, and the reason for adding and subtracting in `pointRand()` is that math.floor does not seem to work with a lowest value of zero.

Comment: Does ptAllow get set to false somewhere? At which part of the script does it stop working after the first successful run? You can return values from functions btw, could help you with your variables.

Comment: Where is the code that would guarantee the `if` is executed more than once? Is there a loop, or event handler,...? Without that, it is normal your code is only executed once.

Comment: are there any errors in the browser developers console? Control+Shift+J brings it up in chrome.  Also it doesn't make sense to add 1 and subtract 1 from the same formula in the first 4 lines of `pointRand()`.  Maybe a thorough code cleanup will find other things?